# UI for Date picker react-datetime Not coming properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui, datetimepicker

```
<Datetime dateFormat={false} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
```

I am using `react-datetime` for time picker

```
 handleChange(newtime){
            this.setState({MTtime: moment(newtime).format("hh:mm:ss a")});
        }
```

[image]

UI Not Coming Properly

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that the library `react-bootstrap-datetimepicker` is deprecated. You should be using `react-datetime` and that library has a `timeFormat` method that mimics `moment.js` http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Use moment().format('x')

Comment: I have updated the question with react-date time UI not coming good

Answer (score 0):

[react-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker) is deprecated, you should uninstall it and use [react-datetime](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime)

To convert the timestamp to a date take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196/4137368)